# Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm: Outside root contents

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

This seems to be a tenacious issue in pycharm.  In my case, I have a set of project roots:

```
libs/     <--- content root
  | lib1/
  | lib2/
  | .../
  | libn/

apps/     <--- content root

notebooks/ <--- content root
```

Each has been flagged as a "sources" folder in the content roots dialog as part of this debugging process.

When I open a `.ipynb` inside `notebooks/`, and run, say:

```
import os
```

The result is the following error message:

```
Run Error
.../path-to-ipynb/foo.ipynb is outside root contents directory
```

This is the new pycharm 2020.2..., fully updated.

How does one get around this?

Comment: do you have the professional or community edition

Comment: @KetZoomer professional

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, worked around by setting `c.ContentsManager.root_dir = 'c:/path_to_notebook_dir'` in my `jupyter_notebook_config.py` to point to the directory containing the notebook.